# $X,Y$ i.i.d, $P(X+Y=0)=1$ Determine the characteristic function of $X$.

Tags: probability-theory

$X,Y$ i.i.d, $P(X+Y=0)=1$ Determine the characteristic function of $X$.

I'd like a hint to approach this problem.

Comment: The characteristic function of $X+Y$ is the square of that of $X$.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Probably for the lack of personal input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d., the characteristic function of the sum satisfies
$$ \phi_{X+Y}(t)=\phi_X(t)\phi_Y(t)=\phi_X(t)^2$$
but on the other hand $\phi_{X+Y}(t)=1$ for all $t$ since $X+Y=0$ almost surely.

So $\phi_X(t)$ is a continuous function with $\phi_X(0)=1$ and $\phi_X(t)^2=1$ for all $t$. What must $\phi_X$ be?

Comment: $\phi _X = 1$ a.s. since $\phi_X(0) = 1$.

Comment: "Almost surely" doesn't make sense here since $\phi_X$ is a function, not a random variable. And of course the continuity of $\phi_X$ is needed to make this conclusion.

Comment: the question is actually kind of the fourier transform of at dirac function..

Comment: A random variable is a measureable function? If $X=-Y$ a.s. and as said, they are measureable functions, then "almost surely isnt needed since $\phi_X$ is a function" doesnt make sense. What am I missing?

Comment: I'm saying the statement "$\phi_X=1$ almost surely" doesn't make sense. Instead simply say $\phi_X(t)=1$ for all $t$.

Comment: Ahh I see it now! The integral is zero on the null set ofc!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Prove that $X = Y = 0$ almost surely.